# jQuery Post Object

Tags: jquery, object, post

How would I go about turning the following code into an object post instead of a string post?

```
var dataSend =   "uniqueID="+uniqueID
        +"&date="+date
        +"&mealNum="+mealNum
        +"&mealName="+mealName
        +"&foodID="+foodID
        +"&amount="+amount;

$.post("updatefood.php", dataSend, function(data){
    $("#errorSpan").html(data);
});
```

I.E. something along the lines of:

```
var dataSend =   {uniqueID: uniqueID},
                {date: date};

$.post("updatefood.php", dataSend, function(data){
    $("#errorSpan").html(data);
    //location.reload();
});
```

But that clearly doesn't work, I cannot figure out the formatting for these objects.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Passing in an object vs a key/value pair string will result in the same thing ending up at the server. Internally, jQuery will convert an object that was passed into the data parameter into a param string if it isn't already a string.

Comment: Right now you have two objects seperated by a comma, as an object starts and stops with the curlybraces, and not one object with comma seperated key/value pairs. There is no need to quote any of those keys, nor the values if they are variables etc. Kevin is rigth, an object will be converted to the approriate string by jQuery, so it really does'nt matter.

Comment: To answer my own question, there is no advantage to using an object instead of a string (other than the code looking cleaner, IMO), because as Kevin and adeneo said, jQuery converts the object into a string (and does not escape ampersands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as dataSend:

```
var dataSend= {
    'uniqueID': uniqueID,
    'date': date,
    'mealNum': mealNum,
    'mealName': mealName,
    'foodID': foodID,
    'amount': amount
};

$.post("updatefood.php", dataSend, function(data){
    $("#errorSpan").html(data);
    //location.reload();
});
```

Comment: When you are posting, jQuery will take this in object form and convert it to the right format to send to the server. The server will get it in the body of the HTTP request with the "&" characters between the various parameters.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @LeeMeador I simply answered what was asked, i.e. changing dataSend from string to object.

Comment: @LeeMeador  I understand that, but if one of the variables I'm including in the string contains a "&", it would fudge up the whole thing.  That's why I was interested in using an object instead.

Comment: @CyrilN.  :)  Btw.. are these considered "JSON" objects or just generic objects?

Comment: It can be a tricky question. I would say that these are considered object because they are created in the javascript language. JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" and is use to represent data structured like Javascript. So JSON would be, IMO, the data you exchange between two peers, that can be interpreted as Javascript.

Comment: JSON is always a string. If it is an object, it is not JSON. JSON can be converted to an object or array, however, after conversion, it is no longer JSON, it's an object or array. If the above were a string, it would not be valid JSON because JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks(+1) for the precision

Comment: @CyrilN. I agree... looking at JSON objects in other people's code, some of them 'resemble' the object we've created here, but a lot of them have completely different notation.  Perhaps they are all the same data structure internally.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for clearing that up... so the above is an object, but not JSON because JSON is just a string representation of a potential future object?

Comment: @CyrilN. Yep. Sorry to not make it clear I liked your answer and was expanding upon it only in case the more info was needed.

Comment: @LeeMeador Lee, do you perchance know if the object -> string conversion that jquery does automatically escapes ampersands and whatnot?  For example, if I passed a string '&variable=100' as a mealName for instance, would it safely not post that variable and instead just post the string itself as a mealName?

Comment: @LeeMeador I was thinking about commenting about that, that it would be a great precision ;)

Comment: It does not. Read [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/prevent-ampersand-from-splitting-up-data-string-during-ajax) where it shows how to take care of ampersands and stuff and unicode chars. Getting them back on the server takes some work too and that link discusses PHP's way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You may need quotes around your objects in your data:

```
var dataSend =  {'uniqueID' : uniqueID, 'date' : date, ... };

//POST remains the same
$.post("updatefood.php", dataSend, function(data){
    $("#errorSpan").html(data);
    //location.reload();
});
```

*(You also can include all of the pairs within a single set of braces)*

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataSend =   {uniqueID: uniqueID, date: date};
```

you were almost there.